# MySQL select statment not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following statement which works fine in `HeidiSQL`, but it is not returning any data when used in my PHP code:

```
$query="Select Left(SiteName, 4) from sites order by SiteName";
```

It works when I remove the `Left` function:

```
$query="Select SiteName from sites order by SiteName";
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probably returning data correctly but the column (in php associative array which are you probably using) is named `Left(SiteName, 4)`, try using:

```
$query="Select Left(SiteName, 4) AS `SiteName` from sites order by SiteName";
```

It should work.

Comment: I'll bet $5 this is the answer. This is why people should not only post the code that gets rows, but post the code that uses the retrieved data too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set alias to the column `Left(SiteName, 4)` which will return data to PHP,

```
$query="Select Left(SiteName, 4) AS SOME_NAME from sites order by SiteName";
                                 ^^   ^^^^^
```